# .htaccess to limit folder/site access to local machines only

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server

So I would like to limit say:

www.website.com/folder to local addresses only on say, a network of 192.168.0.x via .htaccess. But I would still want the entire www.website.com to be accessable. I have read you can do this w/ the .htaccess file in the /folder but I am uncertain of the code to put into the .htaccess file. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.x/24
```

Should do it.

Comment: That seems to block all. What if I changed the order? Also, how would you add multiple ranges? For instance our VPN users are on a 172.x.x.x range and they need to access it as well. Thanks!

Comment: Tried:

order allow,deny
allow from 192.168.0.0/24
deny from all


Still blocks internal.

Comment: For extra ranges, just add more "allow from" statements on subsequent lines.  I'm not sure why that's blocking everything; is that definitely the range that the requests come from?  There's no NAT-performing router or firewall in the way?

Comment: Nope no nat-performing router/fw in the way, But the router/fw is the gateway on these machines, but it should all be on the local side of things.

Comment: This will need to be specified in the proper area, such as in a `Directory` block.  See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_access.html